# Create adjacency matrix by comparing all rows using a subset of string columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scipy, adjacency-matrix, pdist

I have a Pandas dataframe with three columns, `id` (a unique identifier) and then three string columns `event_one`, `event_two` and `event_three`, as follows:

```
test_df.head()

    id  event_one  event_two  event_three
0   N1  'aaa'      'abc'      'xyz'
1   N2  'bbb'      'abc'      'uvw'
2   N3  'ccc'      'def'      'xyz'
3   N4  'aaa'      'def'      'uvw'
4   N5  'aaa'      'abc'      'zzz'
```

I would like to create an adjacency matrix (as a dataframe) that, for all pairs of IDs, will test for string equality across each event column, and then compute the fraction of events that match out of the total number of events.

For example, if we compare `N1` with `N5`, the associated entry in the adjacency matrix for that pair will be 2/3 (or 0.66..), since they match on `event_one` and `event_two`, but not `event_three`.

Using the `test_df` example above, the final adjacency matrix (represented as a Pandas dataframe) would look as follows:

```
      N1    N2    N3    N4    N5
      ----------------------------
N1|   -     1/3   1/3   1/3   2/3
N2|   1/3   -     0     1/3   1/3
N3|   1/3   0     -     1/3   0
N4|   1/3   1/3   1/3   -     1/3
N5|   2/3   1/3   0     1/3   -
```

The code I have written so far (see below) uses `pdist` and a lambda expression but is based on `event_one` only. How can I extend this to all three event columns and then calculate the final computation, or is there a better way of doing this?

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

# Create the example dataframe
events = {'id': ['N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'N4', 'N5'], 
          'event_one': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'aaa', 'aaa'],
          'event_two': ['abc', 'abc', 'def', 'def', 'abc'],
          'event_three': ['xyz', 'uvw', 'xyz', 'uvw', 'zzz']}
df = pd.DataFrame(events, columns=['id', 'event_one', 'event_two', 'event_three'])

# Create an adjacency matrix by comparing event_one using pdist

index_ndarray = df['id'].values
event_one_series = df['event_one']
dm = pdist(event_one_series[:, None], lambda u, v: 1 if u == v else 0)
event_one_matrix_df = pd.DataFrame(
    squareform(dm),
    dtype='str',
    index=index_ndarray,
    columns=index_ndarray)
event_one_matrix_df

    N1      N2      N3      N4      N5
N1  0.0     0.0     0.0     1.0     1.0
N2  0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
N3  0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
N4  1.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     1.0
N5  1.0     0.0     0.0     1.0     0.0
```

Any suggestions would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to select the `event` like columns, then use [`pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) and pass a custom lambda function `f` which compares the pair wise rows and returns the fraction of events matched:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

f = lambda u, v: (u == v).sum() / len(u)
a = squareform(pdist(df.filter(like='event'), f))
d = pd.DataFrame(a, index=df['id'].tolist(), columns=df['id'].tolist())
```

---

```
print(d)
         N1        N2        N3        N4        N5
N1  0.000000  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333  0.666667
N2  0.333333  0.000000  0.000000  0.333333  0.333333
N3  0.333333  0.000000  0.000000  0.333333  0.000000
N4  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333  0.000000  0.333333
N5  0.666667  0.333333  0.000000  0.333333  0.000000
```

Comment: @RaymondBennett Glad I could be of help :) .